# why i can not remove elements of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanted to ask, I have an array and I want to eliminate some elements in the array with elements that I have stored in an array, so the illustrations like this:

array1 = process, of, gathering, mature, crops, from, the, fields, Reaping, is, the, cutting
array2 = of, from, the, is, a, an

if there are elements in array1 is also an element of array2. then these elements will be eliminated.

the method I use like this:

```
var array1 = ["of","gathering","mature","crops","from","the","fields","Reaping","is","the","cutting"];
var kata = new Array();
kata[0] = " is ";
kata[1] = " the ";
kata[3] = " of ";
kata[4] = " a ";
kata[5] = " from ";


for(var i=0,regex; i<kata.length; i++){
        var regex = new RegExp(kata[i],"gi");
        array1 = array1.replace(regex," ");
    }
```

why I can not immediately eliminate the elements of array?

I had been using the method:
when I want to eliminate some elements that are in array1 then the array is my first change into a string by means of:

```
var kataptg = array1.join (" ");
```

however, if using that method there are several elements that should be lost but can be lost because the pattern did not like the array kata as above.

suppose the word **"of"**, the pattern of the array **kata = "of";** but on the pattern **array1 = "of";**

how do these elements can be removed even though the writing patterns differ from those in the array kata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Simplified from
# http://phrogz.net/JS/Classes/ExtendingJavaScriptObjectsAndClasses.html#example5
Array.prototype.subtract=function(a2){ 
   var a1=this;
   for (var i=a1.length-1;i>=0;--i){ 
      for (var j=0,len=a2.length;j<len;j++) if (a2[j]==a1[i]) {
        a1.splice(i,1);
        break;
      } 
   } 
   return a1;
}

var a1 = "process of gathering mature crops from the fields".split(" ");
var a2 = "of from the is a an".split(" ");
a1.subtract(a2);
console.log(a1.join(' '));
// process gathering mature crops fields
```

If performance is an issue, there are clearly better ways that are not O(m*n), such as pushing the words from `a2` into a object for constant-time lookup so that it's a linear-time pass through the source array to drop the ignored words, O(m+n):

```
var a1 = "process of gathering mature crops from the fields".split(" ");
var a2 = "of from the is a an".split(" ");
var ignores = {};
for (var i=a2.length-1;i>=0;--i) ignores[a2[i]] = true;
for (var i=a1.length-1;i>=0;--i) if (ignores[a1[i]]) a1.splice(i,1);
console.log(a1.join(' '));
// process gathering mature crops fields
```

Here's one more solution using regex (probably O(m+n)):

```
var s1 = "process of gathering mature crops from the fields";
var a2 = "of from the is a an".split(" ");
var re = new RegExp( "\\b(?:"+a2.join("|")+")\\b\\s*", "gi" );
var s2 = s1.replace( re, '' );
console.log( re ); // /\b(?:of|from|the|is|a|an)\b/gi
console.log( s2 ); // "process gathering mature crops fields"
```

Comment: @user495688 There isn't an explanation, there's working code and the output it produces. If you have a question about specific code, research it or ask here.

Comment: @user495688 The way you created your a2 was inefficient to type. It doesn't matter how you have your array; I was simply creating the array in my own way so that each of my code samples was working on its own, without relying any external setup.

Answer (score 4):

The items in array1 don't have quotes around them, so JavaScript thinks they're (undefined) variables.

Assuming you've fixed that (and the stray quotes), your next problem is you're calling replace() on an array object. replace() only works on strings.

Comment: sorry..i'm forget to give quotes in my array, but i'm sure that my real code have quotes because i get it from var str which replace in array with split();

Comment: You're missing quotes after "crops and before Reaping".

Comment: oh my god sorry i miss it..but for sure my array is already change in string but why i can't replace some words in different possition?

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the 'discards' in a single reg exp and test each array item for any of them.

By starting at the end of the array you can splice out any discards as you progress towards the start of the array.

```
var array1= ['of','gathering','mature','crops','from','the','fields',
'Reaping','is','the','cutting'],
kata= ['is','the','of','a','from'], L= array1.length,
rx= RegExp('^('+kata.join('|')+')$','i');

while(L){
    if(rx.test(array1[--L])) array1.splice(L, 1);
}

alert(array1)
```

/*
returned value: (Array)
['gathering', 'mature', 'crops', 'fields', 'Reaping', 'cutting']
*/

(The rx here is= /^(is|the|of|a|from)$/i)